# Calculate difference in days between two dates with conditions

Tags: excel, date

I need help calculating the difference in two dates if certain criterias are met.

When `One` is `1` calculate the difference between the date of that value with  the date when `Move` is `1` for each unique values of `Person`. When the difference in days are calculated, check for the next `1` in `One`, and so on. When `One` and `Move` have `1` in the same row, the value should be 0 (as seen in 14.01.2018). Notice the value in 05.01.2018, value `3` takes the date from 03.01.2018 (not 02.01.2018), as it is the last one if there are leading `1`'s.

The expected values are in `Days` in bold and red:

[image]

I have been trying to do this for days in Python programming software, but without success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you [please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57611554/edit) to include the code you have tried?

Comment: But `05.01.2018` - `03.01.2018` --> `2`, not `3`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are correct. There is a small error in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your description regarding the date in `05.01.2018` is correct, and your screenshot is incorrect, then try:

```
E2: =IF(AND($C2=1,$D2=1),0,IF($C2=1,$A2-AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($D$1:$D2=1)*($B$1:$B2=$B2))*$A$1:$A2,1),0))
```

and fill down.

Use conditional formatting to set the values > 0 to bold/red.

[image]

Comment: This works very well for my sample table. Hopefully it would work with my whole dataset. Will try tomorrow! Many thanks!